# complex conjugate transpose matlab to C

Tags: c, matlab, fft, translate

I am trying to convert the following matlab code to c

```
cX = (fft(inData, fftSize) / fftSize);
Power_X = (cX*cX')/50;
```

Questions:

1. why divide the results of fft (array of fftSize complex elements) by
   fftSize?
2. I'm not sure at all how to convert the complex conjugate
   transform to c, I just don't understand what that line does.

Peter

Comment: the answers below help a lot thanks.  However how can I translate that to C?  Assuming A(2,3) the conjugate is A'(2,-3) with the function performing: real = real and imaginary = -1 * imaginary.  However how does that apply to the whole matrix?  Power_X ends up being a single value.

Answer (score 2):

```
1. Why divide the results of fft (array of fftSize complex elements) by fftSize?
```

Because the "energy" (sum of squares) of the resultant fft grows as the number of points in the fft grows. Dividing by the number of points "N" normalizes it so that the sum  of squares of the fft is equal to the sum of squares of the original signal.

```
2. I'm not sure at all how to convert the complex conjugate transform to c, I just don't understand what that line does.
```

That is what is actually calculating the sum of the squares. It is easy to verify cX*cX' = sum(abs(cX)^2), where cX' is the conjugate transpose.

Comment: doesn't sum(abs(cX)^2) destroy the imaginary component?

Comment: If x=a+ib then **abs(x)^2 = a^2+b^2**, which is of course purely real, however the imaginary component "b" is certainly not "destroyed". As you can verify, **x * conj(x) = (a+ib)(a-ib) = a^2 + b^2** also. That example was for scalar, for vectors multiplying by the transpose squares **and** adds.

Comment: Stuart,  I didn't mean destroy, sorry I mean ignore.  However I forgot that with sum(abs(cX)^2) cX is complex.  So I think one last question, so after multiplying each element in the vector it sums those?  ie  ( cX(1) * cX'(1) ) + ( cX(2) * cX'(2) ) ?

Comment: Yes, that's just how matrix multiplication works when you multiply a row vector times a column vector. Remember that matlab treats "*" as matrix multiply by default. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

Answer (score 2):

1. Ideally a Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) is purely a rotation, in that it returns the same vector in a different coordinate system (i.e., it describes the same signal in terms of frequencies instead of in terms of sound volumes at sampling times). However, the way the DFT is usually implemented as a Fast Fourier Transform (FFT), the values are added together in various ways that require multiplying by 1/N to keep the scale unchanged.

   Often, these multiplications are omitted from the FFT to save computing time and because many applications are unconcerned with scale changes. The resulting FFT data still contains the desired data and relationships regardless of scale, so omitting the multiplications does not cause any problems. Additionally, the correcting multiplications can sometimes be combined with other operations in an application, so there is no point in performing them separately. (E.g., if an application performs an FFT, does some manipulations, and performs an inverse FFT, then the combined multiplications can be performed once during the process instead of once in the FFT and once in the inverse FFT.)
2. I am not familiar with Matlab syntax, but, if [Stuart’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15732800/298225) is correct that `cX*cX'` is computing the sum of the squares of the magnitudes of the values in the array, then I do not see the point of performing the FFT. You should be able to calculate the total energy in the same way directly from `iData`; the transform is just a coordinate transform that does not change energy, except for the scaling described above.

Comment: we do the fft for other calculations that we need.

Comment: @user438431: If you want `Power_X` scaled correctly but do not need the FFT data scaled, then you can remove the division by `fftSize` from `cX = … / fftSize …` (where it divides each element of the vector) to `Power_X = (cX*cX')/(50*(fftSize*fftSize))` (where it is one multiplication [to square `fftSize`, since `Power_X` is the square of energy] and one division on a scalar value), saving `fftSize-2` operations.